# Split address with multiple delimeter to multiple column in SQL

Tags: mysql

`1808  FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN` i am trying to split it in 3 column based on `,` comma.

I have used `select substring_index(OwnerAddress,',',1),substring_index(OwnerAddress,',',-1)  from housingdata;` it will give me only 2 values however i am lookking for 3 values in 3 different column.

i am using Mysql Workbench. can anyone guide on how to split string with multiple delemter in sql.

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? Nb I would do this before load to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> set @a = '1808  FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN';

mysql> select trim(substring_index(@a, ',', 1)) as address,
  trim(substring_index(substring_index(@a, ',', 2), ',', -1)) as city,
  trim(substring_index(@a, ',', -1)) as state;
+--------------------+----------------+-------+
| address            | city           | state |
+--------------------+----------------+-------+
| 1808  FOX CHASE DR | GOODLETTSVILLE | TN    |
+--------------------+----------------+-------+
```

On the other hand, if you want these three data elements to be separate, you should store them in three separate columns. This sort of query is bound to be trouble if someone has an address that contains a comma.

See https://linguaholic.com/linguablog/commas-in-adresses/

> 4344 Lynn Ave., Building F, Apt. 4B, Merrill, WI 54452